# Dropdown Slide Form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

how do I add it to a customer in the dropdown, the customer is furmulário prenchido?

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.Label(Resources.Client, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.DropDownList("ClientId", "Choose Client")
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.clientId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Client.active)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Client.active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            @Html.Label(Resources.Active, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#ClientId").change(function () {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("SelectClient")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#ClientId").val() },
                success: function (Client) {

                        $("#ClientId").append('<option value="'
                            + Client.name + '"></option>');
                        $("#ClientNif").append('<option value="'
                            + Client.nif + '"></option>');
                },
                error: function (ex) {

                }
            });
            return false;
        })


    });
</script>
```

public JsonResult SelectClient(int? id)
        {
            Client Client = new Client();

```
        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            Client = db.Clients.Find(id);
        }
        return Json(Client);
    }
```

was supposed to click on the dropdown and see a form with all the data of a client, but when clicking the dropdown form data does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform a jquery selector operation on the name of the selection html control. Therefore *$("#ClientId")* is invalid in your context.

To fix, Try modifying the following code

```
                    @Html.DropDownList("ClientId", "Choose Client")
```

to

```
@Html.DropDownList("ClientId",Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),"Choose Client")
```

Also, replace *onchange* event with *click* event.

```
$(".form-group select[name='ClientId']").on("click", function () {
        // Populate Data
                            });
```